# When Worklight Adapter release java Objects?

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have `Worklight HTTP Adapter`, which creates Java Object, this object makes connection with DB, fire specified query and returns result to adapter, which in turn returns the result to mobile application.

The Java Object closes connection of `Database` in finalize method, but problem is that finalize method have not been called even after finishing the adapter call.

I have also assigned null to object before returning from adapter.

Hence, I want to know when the Adapter releases Java Object, and when its finalize method will be Called?

Comment: Finalizers aren't guaranteed to ever be called. You need to rework your code to close the connection based on some other event, or better yet, use a connection pool.

Comment: @chrylis, how to use connection pool in Java and whats its advantages?

Comment: how come you are not using a database adapterr to do that call for you.  You can call one adapter from another

Comment: @tik27 I have to connect with many databases and hence I am not using database adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDoc says about finalize():

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.

So, your finalize method invokes when GC will start.